# Javascript Object and Variable w/ same name?

Tags: javascript, variables, loops, object, global-variables

I'm a new coder trying hard to interpret some sample code.
In the project I'm looking at, there's both a 'chat' object and 'Chat' variable (both shown below).
On the same .js page where the 'chat' variable is defined, theres a for loop variable referencing 'chat' (shown below), but is it referencing the 'chat' object or 'chat' variable? Are the two working together or entirely separate? I'm having trouble understanding this concept--- Anything helps!

**VARIABLE**

```
var course, chat;
exports.setChat = function(c, ch){
    course = c;
    chat = c.get('chats')[ch];
$.mainContainer.title = chat.title;
updateView();
};
```

**OBJECT**

```
var Chat = new Schema({
    title: {type:String, required: true, trim:true},
    user: userStub,
    content: {type:String, required: true, trim:true},
    comments: [Comment],
    time: {type:Date, required: true}
});
```

**FOR LOOP**

```
var updateView = function(){
    for(var i = 0; i < chat['comments'].length; i++){
```

Comment: Javascript is case-sensitive, so `chat` and `Chat` are completely different variables.

Answer (score 0):

In this case "chat" is a variable and "Chat" is an object type, they definitely aren't the same, as Barmar said, Javascript is case-sensitive, and object types start with an upper-case letter, so you can recognize if it's a variable or an object. And also, text color helps :)